# Need help making Hilbert Curve with numbers in python

Tags: python

I want to make a function that will create a Hilbert Curve in python using numbers. The parameters for the function would be a number and that will tell the function how many times it should repeat. To make a Hilbert Curve you start with 'L', then that turns into '+RF-LFL-FR+', and then 'R' turns into '-LF+RFR+FL-' How should I do this?

```
#Here is what I've made so far
def hilbert(num):
  s = 'L'
  for i in range(num-1):
    s = s.replace('L','+RF-LFL-FR+')
    b = 'R'
    for i in range(num-1):
      b = b.replace('R','-LR+RFR+FL-')
      end = s + b
  return end
It crashes completely when you enter 1, I tried to use to code I made for the Koch snowflake but I wasn't sure how to use the two variables.

#Here is the results for when I use the function
hilbert(1)
#It returns
a crash bruh
hilbert()
#It returns 
'+RF-+RF-LFL-FR+F+RF-LFL-FR+-FR+-L-LR+RFR+FL-+-LR+RFR+FL-F-LR+RFR+FL-+FL-'


#Here is what I want it to return
hilbert(1)
'L'
hilbert(3)
'+-LF+RFR+FL-F-+RF-LFL-FR+F+RF-LFL-FR+-F-LF+RFR+FL-+'
```

Comment: "you start with 'L', then that turns into '+RF-LFL-FR+'". You have given no explanation of what you mean by this.  A Hilbert Curve is a "continuous fractal space-filling curve".  It is not a string of letters.

Comment: I'm saying that 'L' is replaced by '+RF-LFL-FR+', then 'R' is replaced by '-LF+RFR+FL-', that's how you make a Hilbert Curve out of numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need help making a Hilbert Curve using numbers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58713316/need-help-making-a-hilbert-curve-using-numbers-in-python)

Comment: Hi @KittyWhale, welcome to Stack Overflow :) I see you already posted this question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58713316/need-help-making-a-hilbert-curve-using-numbers-in-python), so I'm voting to close it as a duplicate.
If you're not getting any answers, it could be that it's a very tricky question. In most cases, especially when you are new to programming, it's just that your question could be made clearer. Please have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).